# semi pie chart not display properly when activity change in android

Tags: android, charts

[This is second activity screen which display semi pie chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sS73l.png)

[This is result when second activity use as lauancher activity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UEh2v.png)

I create semi pie chart using canvas at second activity and when i perform intent from first activity to second activity it display same as above image but if when i use second activity as launcher it display perfect semi pie chart.

So you have any solution ?

This is onDraw method :

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
{
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    int height = pxToDp(canvas.getHeight() / 2);
    int width = pxToDp(canvas.getWidth() / 2);
    RectF rectf=new RectF(dpToPx(width - 75), dpToPx(height - 75), dpToPx(width + 75), dpToPx(height + 75));
    RectF inside_rectf=new RectF(dpToPx(width - 55), dpToPx(height - 55), dpToPx(width + 55), dpToPx(height + 56));

    for (int i = 0; i < value_degree.length; i++)
    {
        if (i == 0)
        {
            paint.setColor(color.get(i));
            paint.setAntiAlias(true);
            canvas.drawArc(rectf, 180, value_degree[i], true, paint);
        }
        else
        {
            temp += value_degree[i - 1];
            paint.setColor(color.get(i));
            paint.setAntiAlias(true);
            canvas.drawArc(rectf, temp, value_degree[i], true, paint);
        }
    }
    paint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
    canvas.drawArc(inside_rectf, 180, 180, true, paint);

    paint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
    paint.setTextSize(dpToPx(17));
    paint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.CENTER);
    int xPos = dpToPx((pxToDp(canvas.getWidth()) / 2));
    int yPos = dpToPx((int) ((pxToDp(canvas.getHeight()) / 2) - ((pxToDp((int)paint.descent()) + pxToDp((int)paint.ascent())) / 2))) ;

    canvas.drawText(value, xPos, yPos-50, paint);

    paint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
    paint.setTextSize(dpToPx(11));
    paint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.CENTER);
    canvas.drawText(tag, xPos, yPos, paint);
}
```

Comment: please add more description  instead question and image

Comment: okey i add more information i hope now you can easily understand the problem!!!

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
{
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    float temp = 180;

    int height = pxToDp(canvas.getHeight() / 2);
    int width = pxToDp(canvas.getWidth() / 2);
    RectF rectf=new RectF(dpToPx(width - 75), dpToPx(height - 75), dpToPx(width + 75), dpToPx(height + 75));
    RectF inside_rectf=new RectF(dpToPx(width - 55), dpToPx(height - 55), dpToPx(width + 55), dpToPx(height + 56));

    for (int i = 0; i < value_degree.length; i++)
    {
        Log.e("TempAngel",temp+"");
        paint.setColor(color.get(i));
        canvas.drawArc(rectf, temp, value_degree[i], true, paint);
        temp += value_degree[i];
    }

    paint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
    canvas.drawArc(inside_rectf, 180, 180, true, paint);

    paint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
    paint.setTextSize(dpToPx(17));
    paint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.CENTER);

    int xPos = dpToPx((pxToDp(canvas.getWidth()) / 2));
    int yPos = dpToPx((int) ((pxToDp(canvas.getHeight()) / 2) - ((pxToDp((int)paint.descent()) + pxToDp((int)paint.ascent())) / 2))) ;

    canvas.drawText(value, xPos, yPos-50, paint);

    paint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
    paint.setTextSize(dpToPx(11));
    paint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.CENTER);
    canvas.drawText(tag, xPos, yPos, paint);

}
```

- set "temp" variable at local.